Does sys.dm_exec_query_stats get retained post restore?
I have been given a database backup file.
After restore I ran the script in this db and it shows me the query-wise row counts:
SELECT qs.execution_count,  
    SUBSTRING(qt.text,qs.statement_start_offset/2 +1,   
                 (CASE WHEN qs.statement_end_offset = -1   
                       THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), qt.text)) * 2   
                       ELSE qs.statement_end_offset end -  
                            qs.statement_start_offset  
                 )/2  
             ) AS query_text,   
     qt.dbid, dbname= DB_NAME (qt.dbid), qt.objectid,   
     qs.total_rows, qs.last_rows, qs.min_rows, qs.max_rows  
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs   
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS qt   
WHERE qt.text like '%SELECT%'   
ORDER BY qs.execution_count DESC;

This doesn't however return the same output as what I see when running it on production db.
Is the sys.dm_exec_query_stats values stored at server lever or db level? I mean is the data not retained post restore?

This is an in-memory structure. It doesn't survive re-start of Sql Server or backup/restore.
However, the Query Store data is persisted inside the database. So consider having Query Store turned on for your important databases. I.e., the query store data survives both re-start and backup/restore.
